# how to access the relation ship attribute in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

i am using a hasmany relationship and i have a collection of items that i want to loop through and echo the attributes here is my code that i used and i got different errors like null query and try to get non object

```
 public function sellman(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User' , 'id','sellman');
}
```

here controller

```
$clients = Client::all();
    $sellman = Client::with('sellman')->get();
    return view('admin.client.index',compact('clients','sellman'));
```

and here is view

```
@foreach($sellman as $sellmans)
                                <td>
                                    {{{$sellmans->user->name}}}
                                </td>
                            @endforeach
```

and here is the dd of $sellman

```
Collection {#748 ▼


#items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Client {#694 ▼
      #fillable: array:15 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:18 [▶]
      #original: array:18 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "sellman" => Collection {#746 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => User {#741 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Client {#695 ▶}
```

or i want to know if i cant get it with $clients too its the dd of $clients :

```
Client {#666 ▼


 #fillable: array:15 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:18 [▶]
  #original: array:18 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "sellman" => Collection {#718 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => User {#712 ▼
          #fillable: array:3 [▶]
          #hidden: array:2 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:7 [▶]
          #original: array:7 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #rememberTokenName: "remember_t
```

oken"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK first of all, `sellman` is `hasMany` so you can't access it like this :

`$sellmans->user->name`

So it needs to be like this

```
@foreach($sellman as $sellmans)
   @foreach($sellmans->sellmans as $x)
       $x->name
   @endforeach   
@endforeach
```

Also, you don't have `user` `attribute`. You have `User` model, but the model is defined as `sellmans`

With this line :
`$sellman = Client::with('sellman')->get();` you are getting all `Clients` with many `salesman`.

Comment: ty friend it was my answer . is there any documentation for accessing the diffrent type of relationships in view and get them in cotroller cause i didnt find any on laravel documentaion ty

Comment: Laravel has pretty detailed one, but for relationships, have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I changed the names of the method `(sellman)` because the name of the method was identical with the field name and caused the Conflict to occur.

```
public function sellmanList(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class , 'id','sellman');
}
```

`controller` :

```
$clients = Client::all();
$sellman = Client::with('sellmanList')->get();
return view('admin.client.index',compact('clients','sellman'));
```

`view` :

```
@foreach($sellman as $sellmans)
    @foreach($sellmans->sellmanList as $key=>$user)
        {{$user->name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```